# convert file json in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I would like to turn a json file into a dataframe, but I get the error:
ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.
Can anyone help me?

The json file is as follows:

```
{
    "testCaseResult": {
        "timestamp": 1696257561,
        "testCaseStatus": "Failed",
        "result": "Found nullCount=2. It should be 0",
        "testResultValue": [
            {
                "name": "nullCount",
                "value": "2"
            }
        ],
        "testCaseFailureStatus": {
            "testCaseFailureStatusType": "New",
            "updatedAt": 1696257581779
        }
    }
}
```

the python code I used is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
f = open(fjson )
data = json.load(f)
f.close()
for i in data['testCaseResult']:
    print(i)
testCaseResult_df = pd.DataFrame(data['testCaseResult'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data['testCaseResult'], 'testResultValue', 
                       ['timestamp','testCaseStatus','result',
                       ['testCaseFailureStatus','testCaseFailureStatusType'],
                       ['testCaseFailureStatus','updatedAt']])
print (df)
        name value   timestamp testCaseStatus  \
0  nullCount     2  1696257561         Failed   

                              result  \
0  Found nullCount=2. It should be 0   

  testCaseFailureStatus.testCaseFailureStatusType  \
0                                             New   

  testCaseFailureStatus.updatedAt  
0                   1696257581779
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json contains nested structure. You have to flatten the JSON object before converting to dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import json

fjson = 'C:/dati/json/json_file.json'
with open(fjson) as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(data)

flat_data = {}
for key, value in data['testCaseResult'].items():
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        for nested_key, nested_value in value.items():
            flat_data[f'{key}_{nested_key}'] = nested_value
    elif isinstance(value, list):
        for i, dict_ in enumerate(value):
            for nested_key, nested_value in dict_.items():
                flat_data[f'{key}_{i}_{nested_key}'] = nested_value
    else:
        flat_data[key] = value

testcaseresult_df = pd.DataFrame([flat_data]) # {'testCaseResult': {'timestamp': 1696257561, 'testCaseStatus': 'Failed', 'result': 'Found nullCount=2. It should be 0', 'testResultValue': [{'name': 'nullCount', 'value': '2'}], 'testCaseFailureStatus': {'testCaseFailureStatusType': 'New', 'updatedAt': 1696257581779}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about what is Dataframe.
Dataframe of Pandas is for tabular data consisting of rows and columns.

The json attached by you seems not proper without preprocessing.

```bash
ValueError: Mixing dicts with non-Series may lead to ambiguous ordering.
```

This error comes from the array in your json.
In my thingking, it is reasonable for the error to occur unless you modify the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flatten the nested structure in order to JSON data into a DataFrame

```
def flatten_json(json_obj, parent_key='', separator='_'):
    items = {}
    for key, value in json_obj.items():
        new_key = parent_key + separator + key if parent_key else key
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            items.update(flatten_json(value, new_key, 
separator=separator))
        else:
            items[new_key] = value
    return items
flat_data = flatten_json(data)
testCaseResult_df = pd.DataFrame([flat_data])
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If possible, please add your own output to validate your answer.